# Xpath expression evaluates to an empty nodelist

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am having trouble parsing an xml file and retrieve data from it. Below is the xml and code snippet. 
-----XML (test.xml)-----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<Server>
<IPAddress>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</IPAddress>
<UserName>admin</UserName>
<Password>admin</Password>
</Server>
```

-----Code Snippet: -----

```
public static String getInput(String element)
{
    String value = "";
    try {

        File inputFile = new File("test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document inputData = builder.parse(inputFile);
        inputData.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        String[] elementArray = element.split("/");

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String xpathExpression = element;

        System.out.println("Xpath Expression:" + xpathExpression);
                NodeList node = (NodeList) xPath.compile(xpathExpression).evaluate(inputData, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println(node.getLength());

        if (null != node){
                System.out.println(node.getLength());
                for (int i=0; i<node.getLength(); i++){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println("Node count =" + node.getLength() + ";" + 
                        "Node Name =" + node.item(i).getNodeName()); 

                if (node.item(i).getNodeName() == elementArray[1]){
                    System.out.println(node.item(i).getNodeName()+ "=" + node.item(i).getNodeValue());
                    value = node.item(i).getNodeValue();
                }

            }   
        }           

    }   catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
}
```

The code compiles OK. While running, it just doesn't seem to find the nodes "Server" and it's child "IPAddress". The call to getInput() above would come from main in the format below:

```
getInput("Server/IPAddress");
```

Not sure where it's going wrong and I am really new to Xpath. I was wondering if someone can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outermost element is `<root/>`, not `<server/>`. Your query needs to be

```
getInput("root/Server/IPAddress")
```

if you want to use the full path, or even

```
getInput("/root/Server/IPAddress")
```

to indicate you're starting at the root element. Alternatively, you could have XPath to search for all server elements all over the document:

```
getInput("//Server/IPAddress")
```

---

All of those will output

```
Xpath Expression:root/Server/IPAddress
1
1
0
Node count =1;Node Name =IPAddress
```

instead of

```
Xpath Expression:Server/IPAddress
0
0
```

---

You could somehow prepend one of the prefixes of your choice in the `getInput()` function, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! So, what's the difference between "Server/IPAddress" and "//Server/IPAddress"?

Comment: A `/` in the beginning means that the expression starts at the root node; `//` also does, but scans the whole document (`//` is the `descendant-or-self`-axis). No slash at all means you're starting at the current context, which also is (if not set otherwise) the root node.